# How to select documents using cts query that are in CollectionA and not in CollectionB

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am pretty new to using cts queries so I need some help with something that is, I would think, pretty simple.   I need to select document that are in CollectionA but are not in CollectionB.  How would I modify the below query to insure the documents that are in CollectionB are not selected:

```js
cts.andQuery([cts.fieldRangeQuery('datahubCreatedOn', '>=', xs.dateTime(fn.currentDateTime()).subtract(xs.duration('PT120M'))),  cts.collectionQuery(["CollectionA"])])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [cts.andNotQuery()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.andNotQuery)

```
cts.andNotQuery(
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.fieldRangeQuery('datahubCreatedOn', '>=', xs.dateTime(fn.currentDateTime()).subtract(xs.duration('PT120M'))),  
    cts.collectionQuery(["CollectionA"])
  ]),
  cts.collectionQuery(["CollectionB"])
)
```

Comment: Well.   I knew it would be easy.  Thanks Mads.

Comment: Note that there is also the `cts.notQuery()`, which you could also just wrap the `cts.collectionQuery()` for `CollectionB` and add to the array for the `cts.andQuery()`, but if you have positive and negative criteria, `cts.andNotQuery()` is the better option.